# Inserting small photos (icons) in table

Tags: tables

How can I add small photos (icons), instead of the black boxes

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}\color{black}
Symbol & Language Protocol & DataStoryDesign & Alternative / Considerations\\\hline
Replication & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110} & primary, overlaid, stacked\\\hline
Storyline Foundation & \ding[1]{51} & & degree (1, 1)\\\hline
Block Formation & \ding[1]{51} & & 1, 2 storylines\\\hline
Group Composition  & \ding[1]{51} & & unidirectional\\\hline
Frame Fixation & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110}\ding[2]{110} & unidirectional\\\hline
Progression & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110} & full support\\\hline
Transition & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110} & full support\\\hline
Aggregation & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110} & full support\\\hline
Execution & \ding[1]{53} & & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}progression + interactivity,\\alternative path\end{tabular}\\\hline
Modality & \ding[1]{51} & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}\ding[2]{110}\ding[2]{110}\ding[2]{110}\\\ding[2]{110}\ding[2]{110}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}text, image, visualization\\video, map\end{tabular}\\\hline
Symbolising & \ding[1]{51} & \ding[2]{110}\ding[2]{110} & effect, interactivity\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{DataStoryDesign adapted by design considerations}
\label{tab:DataStoryDesignConsiderations}
\end{table}
```

UPDATE:

I did this but it has 2 problems
The text on the last column stick to the bottom
and the images are not aligned vertically

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}\color{black}
Symbol & Language Protocol & DataStoryDesign & Alternative / Considerations\\\hline
Replication & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} & primary, overlaid, stacked\\\hline
Storyline Foundation & \ding[1]{51} & & degree (1, 1)\\\hline
Block Formation & \ding[1]{51} & & 1, 2 storylines\\\hline
Group Composition  & \ding[1]{51} & & unidirectional\\\hline
Frame Fixation & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png}\includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png}  & unidirectional\\\hline
Progression & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} & full support\\\hline
Transition & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} & full support\\\hline
Aggregation & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} & full support\\\hline
Execution & \ding[1]{53} & & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}progression + interactivity,\\alternative path\end{tabular}\\\hline
Modality & \ding[1]{51} & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png}\includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png}\\\includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} \end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[x]{@{}c@{}}text, image, visualization\\video, map\end{tabular}\\\hline
Expressive Symbols & \ding[1]{51} & \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} \includegraphics[width=0.75cm]{dia/progression_icon.png} & effect, interactivity\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{DataStoryDesign adapted by design considerations}
\label{tab:DataStoryDesignConsiderations}
\end{table}
```

Comment: what icons do you want to insert?

Comment: let's say this
https://imgur.com/a/HiBMo25

Comment: I don't know why it gives warning, it's just a small photo

Comment: Please give the complete code which we can test directly.@Kamran

Comment: You can use `\includegraphics` in the table cell.

Comment: Your code does not compile. To make it easier for all of us, please add the missing lines, until it does. Thank you

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I updated it but it has problems

Comment: I think it needs this package \usepackage{pifont}

Comment: Code starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` ;-) // Many problems have their root cause in the lines you didn't show. See one of the previous comments, speculating ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate part of MWE page layout)

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document document, which we can compile as it is and by which we get information about your document pages layout.
- So far I insert images which you should replace by desired icons (it is unknown, ho are they defined)
- Your `\ding[...]{...}` cause errors. So I remove all `[...]` in them.

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \adjustboxset{height=3ex, 
                  keepaspectratio,
                  valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 0.5pt, hline{3-Y} = 0.1pt,    
             vlines,
             colspec = {l X[0.5,c] X[c,m] X[1.5,1,m]},
             row{1}  = {m, bg=gray!30},
             rowsep  = 3pt
             }
Symbol                  
    & Language Protocol 
                & DataStoryDesign   
                    & {Alternative /\\ Considerations}  \\
Replication             
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                    & primary, overlaid, stacked        \\
Storyline Foundation    
    & \ding{51} &   & degree (1, 1)                     \\
Block Formation         
    & \ding{51} &   & 1, 2 storylines                   \\
Group Composition       
    & \ding{51} &   & unidirectional                    \\
Frame Fixation          
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                    \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                    & unidirectional                    \\
Progression             
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}     
                    & full support                      \\
Transition              
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}  
                    & full support                      \\
Aggregation             
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                    & full support                      \\
Execution               
    & \ding{53} &   & {progression + interactivity,\\
                       alternative path}                \\
Modality                
    & \ding{51} &   {\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                     \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                     \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}  \\[3pt]
                     \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
                     \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} } 
                    &   {text, image, visualization video, map} \\
Symbolising             
    & \ding{51} &   \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                    \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
                    &   effect, interactivity             \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{DataStoryDesign adapted by design considerations}
\label{tab:DataStoryDesignConsiderations}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For unknown reason Image is not shown as is expected ..., maybe will appears later.

Comment: this one was good but those packages like showframe and the red one
mess the whole document, besides the titles should be centered and it breaks some cells' text

Comment: @KamranAsgari, if you would read my code IN MWE and consider comments before `showframe` , you should find out, that in real document this part code you must removed. Its purpose is only to show page layout in this test MWE ....

Comment: @celdor, thank you very much for activate image of table ....

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes in your code. There are macros `\cmark`, `\xmark`, and `\imark` for a tick, a cross, and a small image you have linked; the file name  is `icon.png`, so make sure it is in your project folder. With macros, changes to any symbol will be much more convenient if you decide on something else.

The macro `\TB` is a regular `tabular` to make multi line cells.

In order to maintain minimum spacing between rules and cell contents, there is a convenient package `cellspace` which defines a column `Sx`, which add requires spacing. Here `x` is a regular cell type: `l`, `c`, `r`. The spacing can be altered if you change `\cellspacetoplimit` and/or `\cellspacebottomlimit`.

Note headers are changed to fit the whole table in a page. However, if this is not an option, change font size to `\footnotesize` or even `\scriptsize`.

Here's the code with a screenshot:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

%%% Multi line cells
\NewDocumentCommand\TB{O{c}O{c}m}{%
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}#2@{}}#3\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\cmark{\ding{51}}
\newcommand\xmark{\ding{53}}
\newcommand\imark{\raisebox{-0.2em}{\includegraphics[width=1em]{icon}}}   % \ding{110}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \small
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|c|}
    \hline\rowcolor[gray]{0.8}\color{black}
    Symbol & \TB{Language\\Protocol} & \TB{Data Story\\Design} & \TB{Alternative\\/Considerations} \\ \hline
    %
    Replication          & \cmark & \imark       & primary, overlaid, stacked \\ \hline
    Storyline Foundation & \cmark &              & degree (1, 1) \\ \hline
    Block Formation      & \cmark &              & 1, 2 storylines \\ \hline
    Group Composition    & \cmark &              & unidirectional \\ \hline
    Frame Fixation       & \cmark & \imark\imark & unidirectional \\ \hline
    Progression          & \cmark & \imark       & full support \\ \hline
    Transition           & \cmark & \imark       & full support \\ \hline
    Aggregation          & \cmark & \imark       & full support \\ \hline
    Execution            & \xmark &              & \TB{progression + interactivity,\\alternative path} \\ \hline
    Modality             & \cmark & \TB{\imark\imark\imark\\\imark\imark} & \TB{text, image, visualization\\video, map} \\ \hline
    Symbolising          & \cmark & \imark\imark & effect, interactivity \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{DataStoryDesign adapted by design considerations}
  \label{tab:DataStoryDesignConsiderations}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, is it possible Alternative / Consideration doesnt break ?

Comment: The table is very small, how should I stretch it ?

Comment: Yes. Remove the enclosing macro `\TB{...}` and remove \\. I made a note in the answer about your columns because I wasn't sure what is needed. If you have to maintain full length one line headers, your table will probably not fit. You may need to change `\small` to make even smaller fonts (see my answer).

Comment: _The table is very small, how should I stretch it ?_ The table in your code does not fit. This is why I changed columns. Copy header definition from your code and you get the columns as expected. If you want the table to fit, change the font size. Additionally you could change margins. The packe [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is a convenient approach.